# magento2, add custom javascript to module

Tags: magento2, module, knockoutjs

How should I include `myscript.js` to my module.

the content of requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html':
                'vendor_modulename/template/minicart/item/default.html',
            ??? --> how add myscript.js
        }
    }
};
```

myscript.js?

Answer (score 1):

requiredjs-config.js :

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html':
            'vendor_modulename/template/minicart/item/default.html',
        "<js_reference>":"<your_js_path>/myscript.js"
    }
}
```

};

Ex. `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': '<namespace>/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'`

And use  in template to use it same as you require other js .

Comment: May you provide me more guide, how to pass the flag from myscript.js to  default.html? my initObservable: function () does not work

Comment: using `data-bind` with the element you can bind your js to html element and than write knockout template code in it.

Answer (score 1):

`requirejs-config.js` :

```
var config = {
    map: {

        '*': {
            js_reference: 'Namespace_Module/myscript.js'
        }
    }
};
```

In your `phtml` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','myscript.js'],function($){
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In "html" file, there is no phtml!

Comment: i didn't check in html but try this in html. hopefully it helps